# Import .csv file to Sqlite in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, import

I have a .csv file and I want to import this file putting into my database in android.

Example, the .csv file:

```
| id | name  | dt1 | dt2 | dt3 | 
| 1  | Paul  | 21  | 98  | 91  |
| 2  | John  | 22  | 44  | 11  |
| 3  | George| 21  | 31  | 22  |
| 4  | Ringo | 20  | 10  | 15  |
```

To a thing like that:

```
Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().
rawQuery("Insert into table1(_id, name, dt1, dt2, dt3)
values ( 1, Paul, 21, 98, 91)
values ( 2, John, 22, 44, 11)
values ( 3, George, 21,31,22)
values ( 4, Ringo, 20, 10,15);");
```

So please, how can I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try following code,

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
String line = "";
String tableName ="TABLE_NAME";
String columns = "_id, name, dt1, dt2, dt3";
String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") values(";
String str2 = ");";

db.beginTransaction();
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
    String[] str = line.split(",");
    sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
    sb.append(str[1] + "',");
    sb.append(str[2] + "',");
    sb.append(str[3] + "'");
    sb.append(str[4] + "'");
    sb.append(str2);
    db.execSQL(sb.toString());
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Actually I dont understant what should I write at `FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);` for if csv downloaded in a folder or in a asset folder. I am try to this code `AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.csv");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());` but It gives error **Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed**

Comment: @mehmet You can do that like this. `InputStream is = getAssets().open("myfile.csv");` and then `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));`

Comment: With this, I keep getting `FileNotFoundException` is this because it is looking in Android File System on emulator?

Comment: @Saher, FileNotFoundException generally comes when the path you have defined is not found. Try to print full path in "log" and cross check whether the file you have specified is taken by your code or not.

Comment: What is db in this case?

Comment: @KalaJ Its `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I am getting no such table error :(

Comment: @KalaJ, i think you don't have table created. You should first create table of your need with relevant columns and then need to try this answer. :)

Comment: I created my table in my dbHelper.

Comment: figured out the problem. Actually, I'm saving my table headers parsed from csv into my table. How do I remove the table headers?

Comment: @KalaJ i think you can sub string your original csv string and create a new one which don't have table headers..

Comment: substring, how? I don't know the length of the table header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62601/discussion-between-chintan-rathod-and-kala-j).

Comment: when I declare `SQLiteDatabase db;`, I get the message `Cannot resolve symbol 'beginTransaction'`. How do I fix this? (The same error occurs for 'readLine', 'setTransactionSuccessful', and 'endTransaction').

Answer (score 13):

I suggest using **ContentValues** to insert records. It is easier, will escape quotes, and is less verbose.

Like this, (it will also skip bad lines):

```
 ...
 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
 String line = "";
 db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] colums = line.split(",");
                if (colums.length != 4) {
                    Log.d("CSVParser", "Skipping Bad CSV Row");
                    continue;
                }
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(3);
                cv.put(dbCol0, colums[0].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol1, colums[1].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol2, colums[2].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol3, colums[3].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol4, colums[4].trim());
                db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   db.endTransaction();
```

dbCol0 etc are the column-names of the database, e.g. `_id, name, dt1, dt2, dt3` .

db is a database you get from
`public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase ()` in a [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

#### How to read the CSV file

Copy *file.csv* into the assets folder, and read it like this:

```
String mCSVfile = "file.csv";
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inStream = null;
try {
     inStream = manager.open(mCSVfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
...
```

Comment: In this case where should the .csv file be placed?

Comment: Assets folder (like written)

Comment: What is db and dbCol0 in this case?

Comment: @Kala J added info in answer

Comment: For some reason I am getting, (1) no such table, error.

Comment: Have you created a table?

Comment: yes, ok I fixed it. Problem with above is that it's saving column header from CSV file into the db!

Comment: BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream)); gives null pointer .please help me

Answer (score 3):

**I have added some classes using these classes you can easily import and export your file or db**

for these operation you must have to import these two jar file into your project
***(1) opencsv-1.7.jar*** http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencsv17jar.htm
***(2) poi-3.8-20120326.jar***http://code.google.com/p/mipgsmca12-108-126--online-library/downloads/detail?name=poi-3.8-20120326.jar&can=2&q=
and than import all these four classes, and use based on requirement ...
**ExportFileModule** `

```
public class ExportDatabaseToCSV extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean>{

Context context;
ProgressDialog dialog;
public ExportDatabaseToCSV(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;   
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Exporting SecureIt Data to CSV file");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    CredentialDb db = new CredentialDb(context);//here CredentialDb is my database. you can create your db object.
       File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");        

       if (!exportDir.exists()) 
          {
              exportDir.mkdirs();
          }

      File file = new File(exportDir, "SecureItExportedFile.csv");

      try 
      {
          file.createNewFile();                
          CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
          SQLiteDatabase sql_db = db.getReadableDatabase();//returning sql
          Cursor curCSV = sql_db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CredentialDb.TABLE_NAME,null);
          csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

          while(curCSV.moveToNext())
              {
                 //Which column you want to export you can add over here...
                  String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4),curCSV.getString(5)};
                  csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
              }

          csvWrite.close();
          curCSV.close();
          return true;
      }
      catch(Exception sqlEx)
      {
          Log.e("Error:", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
      }
      return false;
}   

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    if(result)
        Toast.makeText(context, "SqLite Data has been Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context, "SqLite Data has not Exported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
}
```

**ImportModule**

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;

public class MyCSVFileReader {

public static void openDialogToReadCSV(final Activity activity,final Context context)
{
    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");
    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(activity, mPath);
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(".txt");
    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            new ImportCVSToSQLiteDataBase(context,activity,file).execute(); //execute asyncTask to import data into database from selected file.            
        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}

}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.export.importmodule.ListenerList.FireHandler;

public class FileDialog {
    private static final String PARENT_DIR = "..";
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private String[] fileList;
    private File currentPath;

public interface FileSelectedListener {
    void fileSelected(File file);
}
public interface DirectorySelectedListener {
    void directorySelected(File directory);
}
private ListenerList<FileSelectedListener> fileListenerList = new ListenerList<FileDialog.FileSelectedListener>();
private ListenerList<DirectorySelectedListener> dirListenerList = new ListenerList<FileDialog.DirectorySelectedListener>();
private final Activity activity;
private boolean selectDirectoryOption;
private String fileEndsWith;    

/**
 * @param activity 
 * @param initialPath
 */
public FileDialog(Activity activity, File path) {
    this.activity = activity;
    if (!path.exists()) path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    loadFileList(path);
}

/**
 * @return file dialog
 */
public Dialog createFileDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    builder.setTitle(currentPath.getPath());
    if (selectDirectoryOption) {
        builder.setPositiveButton("Select directory", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d(TAG, currentPath.getPath());
                fireDirectorySelectedEvent(currentPath);
            }
        });
    }

    builder.setItems(fileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String fileChosen = fileList[which];
            File chosenFile = getChosenFile(fileChosen);
            if (chosenFile.isDirectory()) {
                loadFileList(chosenFile);
                dialog.cancel();
                dialog.dismiss();
                showDialog();
            } else fireFileSelectedEvent(chosenFile);
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.show();
    return dialog;
}


public void addFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
    fileListenerList.add(listener);
}

public void removeFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
    fileListenerList.remove(listener);
}

public void setSelectDirectoryOption(boolean selectDirectoryOption) {
    this.selectDirectoryOption = selectDirectoryOption;
}

public void addDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
    dirListenerList.add(listener);
}

public void removeDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
    dirListenerList.remove(listener);
}

/**
 * Show file dialog
 */
public void showDialog() {
    createFileDialog().show();
}

private void fireFileSelectedEvent(final File file) {
    fileListenerList.fireEvent(new FireHandler<FileDialog.FileSelectedListener>() {
        public void fireEvent(FileSelectedListener listener) {
            listener.fileSelected(file);
        }
    });
}

private void fireDirectorySelectedEvent(final File directory) {
    dirListenerList.fireEvent(new FireHandler<FileDialog.DirectorySelectedListener>() {
        public void fireEvent(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
            listener.directorySelected(directory);
        }
    });
}

private void loadFileList(File path) {
    this.currentPath = path;
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (path.exists()) {
        if (path.getParentFile() != null) r.add(PARENT_DIR);
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                if (!sel.canRead()) return false;
                if (selectDirectoryOption) return sel.isDirectory();
                else {
                    boolean endsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(fileEndsWith) : true;
                    return endsWith || sel.isDirectory();
                }
            }
        };
        String[] fileList1 = path.list(filter);
        for (String file : fileList1) {
            r.add(file);
        }
    }
    fileList = (String[]) r.toArray(new String[]{});
}

private File getChosenFile(String fileChosen) {
    if (fileChosen.equals(PARENT_DIR)) return currentPath.getParentFile();
    else return new File(currentPath, fileChosen);


   }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setFileEndsWith(String fileEndsWith) {
        this.fileEndsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? fileEndsWith.toLowerCase() : fileEndsWith;
        }
     }

class ListenerList<L> {
private List<L> listenerList = new ArrayList<L>();

public interface FireHandler<L> {
    void fireEvent(L listener);
}

public void add(L listener) {
    listenerList.add(listener);
}

public void fireEvent(FireHandler<L> fireHandler) {
    List<L> copy = new ArrayList<L>(listenerList);
    for (L l : copy) {
        fireHandler.fireEvent(l);
    }
}

public void remove(L listener) {
    listenerList.remove(listener);
}

public List<L> getListenerList() {
    return listenerList;
}
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ImportCVSToSQLiteDataBase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Activity activity;
    Context context;
    File file=null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ImportCVSToSQLiteDataBase(Context context, Activity activity,File file) {
        this.context=context;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.file=file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Importing Data into SecureIt DataBase");
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        dialog.show();
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String data="";
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), file.toString());

           try{
                 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
                   String [] nextLine;

                  //here I am just displaying the CSV file contents, and you can store your file content into db from while loop...

                    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line

                        String accId=nextLine[0];
                        String acc_name=nextLine[1];

                        data=data+"AccId:"+accId  +"  Account_name:"+acc_name+"\n";

                      }
                   return data;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Error for importing file");
            }
        return data="";

  }

protected void onPostExecute(String data)
  {

    if (dialog.isShowing())
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (data.length()!=0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "File is built Successfully!"+"\n"+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "File fail to build", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
   }


}
```

**Steps to use ...**
**(1) For Export SqLiteDb:**
     *new ExportDatabaseToCSV(YourActivityClass.this).execute();*

**(2) For Import SqLiteDb from your selected file:**
    *MyCSVFileReader.openDialogToReadCSV(this, YourActivityClass.this);*

**(3) And Don't forget to add these permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, just these .jar files that make me a bit uncomfortable to use. :/

Comment: Here :)
https://github.com/rogerta/secrets-for-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/au/com/bytecode/opencsv