# Create Database using CSV file Android

Tags: java, android, csv

I am new to Android and I want to create a MySQLite Database using a csv file which is on the sd card. Can you please help me with code.

```
package com.example.nrbapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position_id",""+position);
                startActivity(i);


                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,position + "," + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
        case R.id.action_settings: 
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.muv, R.drawable.auto,
                R.drawable.tractor, R.drawable.commercial
        };
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

> This is my MainActivity which is a image gridview and I need to create a database on click of any image.
>   Please help me with this

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672074/import-csv-file-to-sqlite-in-android

Comment: I have tried that but how do I add that to my code I am getting error like hell.

Comment: show your what you have tried so far and where are you having probs

Comment: @SMR please find my code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create SQLite database from CSV file using technique suggested in this post:

> [How to import load a .sql or .csv file into SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite)

Then you can follow this article to use pre built sqlite database in your application.

> http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/