# Browsing csv file and then import it on android sqlite

Tags: android

Im new to android. Im still need to learn a lot of things. I know some might report this as duplicate but i guess its different. I want to select files first then import it on android sqlite. I have this code where i can select files and it works properly, after i selected a file it goes like Selected file : `"/path/file.csv"` something like that. I've also seen some code to import csv file but those files are just stored it assets folder of the project. What i want is to select the file and execute the import so it will be saved on the database. please help.

> I figured out what i was doing wrong. thanks by the way

Comment: So you need a file picker for the user of your app. Your problem then has nothing to do with .csv or database.

Answer (score 0):

[Import .csv file to Sqlite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672074/import-csv-file-to-sqlite-in-android)

If you say your example is different, you should provide more details/code highlighting the differences.