# Importing the csv file to Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, csv, android-sqlite

I have successfully exported the csv file of my android application database. Now what i want to do is by browse option selecting i can import that csv file and replace it with existing database tables (like as restore).
I have a table in sqlite database name members.

```
Id  == Name == Phone number
1   == Abhi == 11111111
2   == Ram  == 111111223
3   == Alex == 891273932
```

I want to restore the csv file in to my phone database in android application.

Thanks

Comment: SQLite supports CSV importing by default. May not work well with complex CSVs though. Read : https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: Please see this link stackoverflow.com/a/72113923/12272687

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set separator string, then you can import you csv file to the desired Table.

Here am assuming separator as comma(,)

```
.separator ","
.import your_csv_file.csv your_table_name
```

If you use `.help`, you might notice something interesting :

```
sqlite> .help
...
.help                  Show this message
.import FILE TABLE     Import data from FILE into TABLE
...
.separator STRING      Change separator used by output mode and .import
...
```

Comment: It should be mentioned this is from a sqlite shell. The question was asking how to do it in Android

Comment: Fine, can i delete this answer?

Comment: It is a reasonable answer, just needs more clarification on how to get the database file into Android

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
String line = "";
String tableName ="TABLE_NAME";
String columns = "_id, name, phonenumber";
String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") values(";
String str2 = ");";
 
db.beginTransaction(); 
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
    String[] str = line.split(",");
    sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
    sb.append(str[1] + "',");
    sb.append(str[2] + "',");
    sb.append(str[3] + "'");
    sb.append(str[4] + "'");
    sb.append(str2);
    db.execSQL(sb.toString());
} 
db.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
db.endTransaction();
```

Taken from: [Import .csv file to Sqlite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672074/import-csv-file-to-sqlite-in-android)