# Where to store and how to access local database files?

Tags: android, kotlin, local-storage

So I have a CSV file that contains some data necessary for my app. I'm not sure where in the app package should I store the file and how should I access it (**as a file**).

I stored it in the `res/raw` but I can't find a way to access the file.

Here's my code:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.sample/raw/data")
Log.e("TAG", uri.path.toString())

var file = File(uri.path.toString())
Log.e("TAG", file.path)
Log.e("TAG", file.exists().toString())
```

`file.exists()` returns false.

Comment: use assets. . . . .

Comment: You should store the files in your asset directory. I have an answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779210/3145960). As stated in my answer, you can convert your CSV into an SQLite file so that you can run queries in an efficient manner. However, if that is not your intention, you might just put the csv in the asset folder and use that as mentioned in my answer stated above.

Comment: I used the pathname: `//android_asset/data.csv` and file.exists() still returns **false**

Comment: did you put the files in the assets directory before checking `file.exists()`?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565154/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare so is it that I can only get it as an input stream using assets and/or raw?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i did put the file in assets folder

Comment: Yes. Assets and resources are files on your development machine, but they are not files on the device. They are merely entries in the APK file, and you can only get an `InputStream` on them. If you need a file, you would need to first get the `InputStream`, copy the bytes to a file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use that file.